# Send dynamic JSON from client to server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, post

I have a client side written in JavaScript and a server side in Java on spring boot. I have the following JSON array in my client side.

```
[
  {
    "names": [
      {
        "default": "somelink"
      },
      {
        "nr": "somelink"
      },
      {
        "pr": "somelink"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "circle": [
      {
        "ID": [
          {
            "red": "someData"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID2": [
          {
            "blue": "somedata"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "square": [
      {
        "ID3": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "triangle": []
  }
]
```

Now the following properties will always be fixed in the JSON array - `names, circle, square, triangle`. Now in my application you can add however many of these objects you like. So in this example we have two circles, `ID` and `ID2`, both have some data attached (`red and blue`). We have one square `ID3` with no data and no triangles. Each property inside the fixed properties of names, circle, square and triangle can be changed.

Now I would like to send this over to the server side in Java but I am struggling to see how I can do this as my JSON is not static. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please explain more about what do you mean by struggling to see how your JSON properties changed?

At first glance, I can see you can save your self a lot of work by building the JSON object in a different way:

For the whole JSON object for the main properties like (names, circle, square, triangle), you can instead of creating an object with a value of an array to use the following:

```
{
"names": [...],
"circle": [...],
"square": [...],
"triangle": [...]
}
```

For the "names" attribute consider doing this: (at the end it all depends on what type of data(object, array, string,...) you are going to store on each key of (default, nr, pr)

```
"names": {
    "default": "somelink",
    "nr": "somelink",
    "pr": "somelink"
}
```

For Circle key:

Instead of:

```
"circle": [
      {
        "ID": [
          {
            "red": "someData"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID2": [
          {
            "blue": "somedata"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

You can do this:

```
"circle": {
  "ID": [
          {
            "red": "someData"
          }
        ],
  "ID2": [
          {
            "blue": "somedata"
          }
        ]
}
```

So as a whole object you might structure it as the following:

```
{

 "names": {
    "default": "somelink",
    "nr": "somelink",
    "pr": "somelink"
},
 
"circle": {
            "ID": [
                   {
                     "red": "someData"
                   }
             ],
            "ID2": [
                    {
                     "blue": "somedata"
                   }
            ]
},

"square": {
            "ID3": []
},

"triangle": []

}
```

Comment: The objects are dynamic, in this example the circles only contains one object, but they can change to what ever amount. ID could have 5 objects and ID2 might have 0. It's different each time. Likewise the name ID can also be different each time. No property is fixed apart from names, circle, square and triangle. The structure remains the same.

Comment: I edited the answer, can you please clarify more what issues do you have? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, my issues is that I do no know how to pass this JSON into the server side in Java, since the JSON is dynamic and not static.

Comment: So your problem is not succeeding in sending the Object data from the Frontend side using JavaScript? did you parse the Object using JSON.parse(object) method?

Comment: I'm having difficulties in understanding what I need to do in my server to receive the json from the client side, I'm using spring boot. Do I need to create objects? I just want a string of my json to be outputted in my server side.

Comment: Do I need to create objects? That is how I have seen most tutorials do it. Problem is I don't need the object and my JSON properties are different each time.